# Is it possible to find the last peak value in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I want to reach the last peak value for every metrics. Is it possible to find with prometheus? If it is not possible is there any way to find with codeblocks?[image]

I analyzed some metrics data but I couldn't find an algorithms for every metric.

Comment: What do you mean by "every metric"? Literally every metric your prometheus has, like `{job!=""}`, or something more localized?

Comment: Also, define "peak" precisely. What if there is a plato for a minute - is it a peak? Or if you have rising right now metric - should it return current value, or previous peak?

Comment: My metrics more localized, my every metrics have same {job="x"}, and If rising right now, it should return current value. if there is a plato for a minute, it is a peak also

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this to get last peak value

```
last_over_time((max_over_time({job="x"}[3m] offset -1m) == {job="x"} > {job="x"} offset 1m) [6h:])
```

Here:

- inner part checks that current value is maximal over period [now-2m, now+1m] and strictly bigger than value a minute ago. Other values are filtered out.
- `last_over_time` stretches existing values over periods of missing values.

You might need to adjust used range selectors and offset operator for your situation, as current ones are "educated guess" based on your screenshot.